# how to perform box-cox transformation to single column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, data-science-experience

I am trying to apply a box-cox transformation to a single column but I am unable to do that. Can somebody help me with this issue?

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer

california_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True).frame
california_housing

power = PowerTransformer(method='box-cox', standardize=True)
california_housing['MedHouseVal']=power.fit_transform(california_housing['MedHouseVal'])
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `power.fit_transform` requires the input data in case of a single feature to have shape `(n, 1)` instead of `(n,)` (where `california_housing['MedHouseVal']` is of shape `(n,)`, as it is a `pd.Series`). This can be achieved either by reshaping, i.e. by replacing

```
power.fit_transform(california_housing['MedHouseVal'])
```

with

```
power.fit_transform(california_housing['MedHouseVal'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
```

or, alternatively, and a bit more readable, by simply accessing a list of columns (which gives a `pd.DataFrame`) with `california_housing[['MedHouseVal']]` instead of a single column (which gives a `pd.Series`) with `california_housing['MedHouseVal']`, i.e. by using

```
power.fit_transform(california_housing[['MedHouseVal']])
```

Note that

```
print(california_housing['MedHouseVal'].shape)
print(california_housing[['MedHouseVal']].shape)
```

prints

```
(20640,)
(20640, 1)
```

An other option would be to use `scipy.stats.boxcox`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from scipy.stats import boxcox

california_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True).frame
california_housing['MedHouseVal'] = boxcox(california_housing['MedHouseVal'])[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Data needs to be reshaped with `.reshape(-1, 1)`, as there is only a single feature (as the error message tells you). See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. In this approach, why should we have a zero[0]?
`california_housing['MedHouseVal'] = boxcox(california_housing['MedHouseVal'])[0]`

Comment: `scipy.stats.boxcox()` returns a tuple, where the first element, i.e. `boxcox(...)[0]`, is the transformed array, the second is the lambda that maximizes the log-likelihood, etc.. See documentation for details: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html